# What would be the best analysis / analyses for the over time coral bleaching recovery data?

Tags: r, repeated-measures, permutation-test, nested-data, ecology

I am analyzing this MISeq microbial community data with Phyloseq and vegan R-packages from coral hosts and I would much appreciate some help and ideas as this is my first analysis of this kind. 
We have 10 samples of paired bleached and unbleached coral colonies (10 bleached corals and 10 unbleached corals for each spp) from 3 different spp., in 3 different sites, and those corals were tagged and re-sampled from the climax of the bleaching event and afterwards during the bleaching recovery in total in 4 time-points. So we have the variables:

- Species: 3 coral spp.
- Status: 2 levels: 10 bleached and 10 unbleached corals per spp.
- TimePoints: 4 time-points when these same corals were re-sampled
- Reef_Location: 3 sites

I have 2 big questions, around the largest question that would be: "what is the best way to analyze these data":

1. I was planning on running a PERMANOVA on with vegan package, but I am not sure whether to consider some of the variables nested or not. I have tried several combinations, after creating a distance phyloseq object with "Bray" distance called 'physeq.bray.dist', such as:

   ```
   permanova.total <- adonis(physeq.bray.dist~(Status*Species*TimePoint)+(1|Reef_location), 
                             data=as(sample_data(physeq.f.t), "data.frame"), 
                             permutations=9999)
   ```

   I suspect there should be other ways to run more effectively this PERMANOVA, if whether to consider the sites as nested, and I am not sure as how to treat the repeated sampling on the same corals. Any suggestions?... Should I run other tests as well?
2. Further we have 3 data sets, from bacteria, fungi and microalgae (so 16S, ITS1, TTS2). I am starting analyzing all separately, but would like to compare and see interactions among the 3 microbial compartments. What analyses should I be running for this?...